# conflict beetween mootols and ajax script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am not expert programmer and I need an help.
I have a conflict between these codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-1.5.1-core.js"></script>
<script src="src/tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the tooltip.js code is in this package:
http://www.menucool.com/download/tooltip.zip

In the project I will need use the jquery also.
Thank you in advance for your help.
A.

Comment: Why mix mootools and jQuery? This smells of an X/Y problem. Perhaps you tell us what you want to achieve, and we can perhaps help you with achieving the end result instead of fixing something that should not have been done from the start. Also we will not download and unzip something and copy it into a file with mootools to see what your porblem might be, Show us some error messages from the console. Please visit [help] to see how to ask a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using jQuery and mooTools is a must, you can run jQuery in [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) mode. The order of the scripts should look like this to work:

```
<script src"path/to/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="src/tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- this will make jQuery available through the jQuery variable -->
<script type="text/javascript">$.noConflict();</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-1.5.1-core.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the answers.

Unfortunately the suggest does't work.
The project is: with mootools I have a nice underline, withtooltip the tip.
About the request of mplungjan: I am not a programmer, this is the link, please try here:
http://www.indivisibile.it/tooltip/demo2.html
you can see that now mootool is commented.

Thank you and sorry for my english.
A.

Comment: Hi, I've rewritten the mootools code into jQuery, you can see a demo here: http://jsbin.com/haxatucuyu/1/ .Hope it helps

Comment: Hello George, thank yop very much, now is perfect. Regards from Italy and have a nice day.

Comment: No problem, dont forget to mark my answer as the right one. Thanks.